# JavaScript Historic back/forward

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I'm building a little CoffeeScript application with 10 buttons and a container (simple). When the user press on one of the button : the container change.

The buttons look like a navbar and instead of using links (that will reload the entire page), I used javascript (Coffeescript, jquery or whatever) to change the content of the page (with some Ajax query to load data).

The problem is that the back and forward button of the browser can't work with that solution... and I need to find a solution for that. Routing maybe ?

I really like the way Asana.com resolved this issue: actually the address change but the content seems not to be entirely reloaded.

What do you suggest ? Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Hashes. The simplest solution is to define an URL hash every time the user clicks on a button. For example:

```
location.href = "#" + button.id;
```

With that, you create a history entry, and the user can press back or forward in the browser.

But how can you check when this happens? There's the `hashchange` event:

```
window.onhashchange = function() {
    var state = location.hash.substring(1); // chomps the initial #
    ...
};
```

Basing your code on the `state` variable, you can trigger your AJAX calls from there.

By the way, you can change your code altogether, using links instead of buttons with an hash as the `href` property, which does *not* reload the page, but creates an history entry and fires the `hashchange` event.

The `hashchange` event is supported by every modern browser (that support `history.pushState` too, a more flexible and powerful way to control your history) and IE8-9.

Comment: Thanks a lot, already heard about a similar solution and you just confirmed what people are saying around. I'll investigate in that way.